# Casting uint32_t to int32_t and comparing them afterwards

Tags: c, stdint

I'm having trouble understanding how does comparing two ints, where one is unsigned int32 and the other one signed int32 work. 
Let's consider this simple program:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a1 = UINT32_MAX;
    int32_t b1 = (int32_t)a1;

    if (a1 == b1)
        printf("Equal");
    else
        printf("Not equal");

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, `a1` exceeds a signed 32-bit integer range, so as I have confirmed while debugging, after it's been casted, `b1` equals `-1`. 
However it still prints "Equal", while those values obviously aren't the same. What is it caused by?

Comment: "to check if a1 value is within range of signed 32-bit integer." --> `in_range = a1 <= INT32_MAX;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An out-of-range conversion to a signed integer type, as you are doing, is **implementation defined**.

On most implementations you're likely to come across, converting the max value for a `uint32_t` to a `int32_t` means retaining the bit pattern and treating it as a signed value.  This means that `b1` gets assigned the value -1.

When you then compare `a1` and `b1`, the **usual arithmetic conversions** apply.   These are spelled out in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type

The highlighted portion is what applies in this case, since `uint32_t` and `int32_t` have the same rank, so the value of `b1` is converted to type `uint32_t`.

When converting an out-of-range value for an unsigned type, this is accomplished by numerically adding or subtracting one more that the max value of the unsigned type repeatedly until the value is in range.  This effectively means that any excess bytes of the source value are truncated and what is left is treated as an unsigned value.

This conversion is spelled out in section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
>   type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than 
>   the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> *3* Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined
>   or an implementation-defined signal is raised

In this case, paragraph 3 applies when you first assign `a1` to `b1`, and paragraph 2 then applies when you do the comparison and `b1` is converted.  So  that means that the value -1 gets converted to the value `UINT32_MAX`, which is why the comparison evaluates to true.

Comment: Good answer.  Pedantic: if `int` was 64-bit, the result would be `"Not equal"` ;-)

Comment: You forgot the *first* line from the first excerpt: "**Otherwise, *the integer promotions are performed on both operands.* Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:**" If `int` is 64 bits, then this clause will convert them both to `int` and then "they are of the same type"

Answer (score 4):

The builtin `==` can only compare values of the same type. If the types of the operands are different, they are converted to a same type beforehand. (See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison) for how this type is chosen.)

In this case, `b1` is converted to `uint32_t` before the comparsion is performed.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the value of a1 will truly be the same before and after casting? I am trying to check if a1 value is within range of signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: @MLapaj Check `a1 < (1U << 31)`

Answer (score 4):

In general, unsigned-to-signed conversions are implementation defined 
([6.3.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3)) as of now (this may change in future versions of the C standard).

In practice, the integers will be two's complement and conversions in either direction will be a no-op—the same data will just be interpreted differently in accordance with how two's complement arithmetic works.

The equality in your case is caused by the signed `b1` getting semantically converted to an `a1`'s unsigned type in the comparison due to [usual arithmetic conversions (6.3.1.8)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8).